# Valgrind for MIPS 64 is giving invalid memory access for basic dynamic allocations

Tags: valgrind, mips64

Getting below output while running valgrind for MIPS64:

-bash-4.3# bin/valgrind ./a.out
Memcheck, a memory error detector
Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info

Command: ./a.out

```
Invalid read of size 8
   at 0x40B6EE4: __ctype_init (in /lib64/libc.so.6)
   by 0x40A7C8C: _init (in /lib64/libc.so.6)
   by 0x40129D8: call_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x4012BC8: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x400328C: _dl_start_user (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
 Address 0xffffffffffff9000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Process terminating with default action of signal 10 (SIGBUS)
   at 0x40B6EE4: __ctype_init (in /lib64/libc.so.6)
   by 0x40A7C8C: _init (in /lib64/libc.so.6)
   by 0x40129D8: call_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x4012BC8: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x400328C: _dl_start_user (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
Invalid read of size 4
   at 0x4019508: __dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x40192D8: _dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
 Address 0xffffffffffff8900 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Process terminating with default action of signal 10 (SIGBUS)
   at 0x4019508: __dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)
   by 0x40192D8: _dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)

HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated

All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
 Bus error
```

Valgrind Libraries used: 3.13, 3.15 and 3.22 but same issue.

```
while(1)
{
   int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

   *ptr = 1;
   printf("#### Ptr %d\n", *ptr);

   free(ptr);
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: MIPS64 isn't much used these days. What hardware is this on?

Comment: I just tried your example on a MIPS64 machine, no problem.

Comment: cpu model used is: Cavium Octeon III V0.2  FPU V0.0

Comment: configure command is as follows:                                                                  
./configure --host=mips64-linux-gnu CC=/opt/CAVIUMsdk312/OCTEON-SDK/tools/bin/mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc CXX=/opt/CAVIUMsdk312/OCTEON-SDK/tools/bin/mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-g++ CFLAGS="-march=octeon2 -mabi=64" --prefix=<path to copy exe>

Comment: Much the same for me Cavium Octeon III V0.2 FPU V0.0 Debian 10.13 buster 4.9.79-UBNT_E300 but I just ran ‘configure’.

Comment: I cross compiled the library over x86 linux machine.